# Can't get to dynamically style one item from a v-for vue 3

Tags: css, vuejs3, v-for

I am trying to get the active item from this menu list to display in a different style. When I reload the page, the style gets applied for a split second, then disappears and all items share the exact same style.

There is a similar thread saying the solution is to actually have the item available as a data property in that component. I have tried that too, and it would not work. It makes more sense to have all the data from a computed property since I am using Vuex for data storing.

The template:

```
    <li class="topic" 
    v-for="topic in topics" 
    :key="topic" 
    @click="selectTopic($event, topic)"
    :class="{'active': topic === current}"
    >
    {{topic}}</li>
```

and the script:

```
computed: {
    topics: function(){
        return this.$store.state.topics
    },
    current: function() {
        return this.$store.state.current_topic
    }
},
```

The current_topic is updated with the `selectTopic` method in this component. It all works fine, except I can't get the current_topic to have a distinctive style.

Oh, on the styles I simply have `.topic.active {border:yellowgreen solid 0.5em;}`. If I do `topic:active` then the style gets applied when I click but only for the time I am clicking (also if I hold), but it does not get applied when reload not even for a split second.

Any leads? thank you :-)

Comment: I have also tried using a getter to access the state data I retrieve on the computed properties. Nada.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a conclusion / closing of this thread. The code I presented is correct. The problem had to do with a getter which was converting the current_topic into a title. This is why topic and current did not match inside the class binding. I figure it is still worth leaving the thread since it might be helpful for somebody else dealing with class binding inside a v-for.